# Typescript - TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, visual-studio

I have this problem when I try to "firebase deploy"

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /workspace/src/index.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at checkSyntax (node:internal/main/check_syntax:58:26) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

Node.js v18.15.0; Error ID: 037e0eb0
```

and I don't know know to fix it.

My files are:

- package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1"
  }
}
```

- tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "moduleDetection": "force"
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I am very happy if someone can help me to fix it. Thanks

I tryed to add in the package.json

```
"type": "module"
```

but nothing. Also to change in the tsconfig.json

```
"module": "ESNext" or "ES2023"
```

without success

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If that's the full package.json it seems to me that you are missing some things that are usually created when you properly use the `firebase init` command.

I suggest you to create a new project from scratch following the official guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript (remember to select typescript as language from the wizard and add the features you need. I guess you will need "functions" and "emulators"), change the .firebaserc so that it points to the previous project and then copy your source code into the new project.